How can i get placeholder text from prompt in js
I need to get the default value from prompt via selenium. If this is my prompt :
prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");

I want to get "Harry Potter" to my String
I tried use this :
alert.Text;

But i get the first text "Please enter your name:"
The prompt :
var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");


I ran the following code.
var person = prompt("Please enter your name:", "Harry Potter");
alert(person)

The result was the expected "Harry Potter".
Are you sure the code is not working?
